# High volume imports

Tags: largedatavolumes

I would like to know best practices when dealing with nightly loads of high volume of information, let's say, importing around 2.500.000 regs. per day into CRM.

thanks, 
Daniel

Comment: Depends on how you are importing them and what processing needs done.  Are you simply doing a straight import of data?  That's simple then and will take a little while but not super long.

Comment: Are those new records or updates?  While Salesforce can handle millions of records and even tens of millions of records (if you're careful), hundreds of millions of Salesforce records would require planning.  If these are all new records, you'd have 250 million in a hundred days.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with [this article](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/The_Salesforce_Bulk_API_-_Maximizing_Parallelism_and_Throughput_Performance_When_Integrating_or_Loading_Large_Data_Volumes) - but there are several articles/webinars on the [developer force website](https://developer.salesforce.com/search?q=bulk%20api) re best practices around large data loads